# Binding for nested ListView not working

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview

I have a nested ListView, but the ItemSource binding is never firing. Am I missing something in here? Here you can see my parent list view, which is binding just fine. But the nested one does not.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0">
                                    <CheckBox IsChecked="True" Margin="0,0,5,0"></CheckBox>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="0,0,15,0"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="Task Set Loop: "/>
                                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Scenarios}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <ListView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding ChildItems, Converter={StaticResource DebugBindingConverter}}">
                                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0">
                                                <CheckBox IsChecked="True" Margin="0,0,5,0"></CheckBox>
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="0,0,15,0"/>
                                                <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding DependentTaskName}"/>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                </ListView>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: Post the code for your data objects and your converter.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My binding for the ChildItems was at the wrong level. Changed that line to:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.ChildItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

For UWP we can get it like this

```
<GridView x:Name="abc" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.Companies,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"></GridView>
```